# How can I find the files based on the file name in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to make repeated changes in multiple files using NotePad++. I have multiple .cs files in multiple folders. I want to make the changes in program.cs file in all folders. I cannot find a way to filter the files based on the file name using Notepad++.
So, let me know how can i proceed this using NotePad++?

Answer (score 0):

You may have two options using the Search > Replace... features.

First, you can open all the relevant files you wish to change. Then there is a "Replace All in All Opened Documents" button that would make the Find/Replace change across all files.

Second and perhaps better, use the Search > **Find in Files** tab. Here you can specify your Find/Replace value using Filters ("program.cs") and Directory, including checking "In all sub-folders."

In either case, you'll need to specify your Find/Replace values individually, if you need to make multiple changes.